# How can I refresh a modal which is always open from outside its code in ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I wanted to try a drawer in my ionic project and found this tutorial I followed: https://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-a-sliding-drawer-component-for-ionic-2/

I added the necessary code to my app.html and app.component.ts so it would always be open, this is precisely the problem. Because it's always open I can't update the content of the drawer using lifecycle hooks(at least I think so).

This is how I incorporated the drawer in my app.html.

```
<drawer [options]="drawerOptions"></drawer>
```

And here is the git to my complete Code: 
https://github.com/CelinaSkywalker/sitAndOrderV1.git

(This is my first question in StackOverFlow, if you have any constructive critique on my asking style, I would love to hear it)

Comment: i think you can use event and publish for that but let me check with your code too

Comment: Could you give me some more insight? or a link to an explanation how to do that? :)

Comment: Please this https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/ if anything needed let me know

Comment: It works beautifullyl! Thanks for helping a noobie!!

Comment: welcome @celina